# Datatable not showing properly in the laravel blade file

Tags: laravel, datatable

I'm getting one issue in the datable. I added datatable in my laravel blade file, but when I clicked on the menu (call blade file). Then it shows a normal table, but when I refresh the same page again and then it shows datatable properly. My question is when I click on the menu(call blade file), then why it is not showing datatable properly. It shows a normal table only. How to fix this.

please check images[this image is before refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dp4XP.png)

[this image is after refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cScWx.png)

and this is my blade file

```html
@extends('backEnd.layout')


        <!--page level css starts-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<!--end of page level css-->



@section('content')
    <div class="padding">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-header dker">
                <h3>Product List</h3>
                <small>
                    <a href="{{ route('adminHome') }}">{{ trans('backLang.home') }}</a> /
                    <a href="#">Product List</a>
                </small>
            </div>
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="table"  >
                <thead class=" primary">
                <tr >
                    <th class="text-center">Category</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Title</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Make</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Rate</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($records as $record)
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">{{$record->section_title}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{$record->title_en}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{$record->make}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">{{$record->rate}}</td>
                        <td class="text-center">@if($record->status != 1) Used
                        @else New @endif
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
@section('footerInclude')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#checkAll").click(function () {
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
        $("#action").change(function () {
            if (this.value == "delete") {
                $("#submit_all").css("display", "none");
                $("#submit_show_msg").css("display", "inline-block");
            } else {
                $("#submit_all").css("display", "inline-block");
                $("#submit_show_msg").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
    </script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#table').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

@endsection
```

any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Your Blade file should be like this.
You should add script files before you write your script.

```
  @extends('backEnd.layout')


<!--page level css starts-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
<!--end of page level css-->



@section('content')
<div class="padding">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header dker">
            <h3>Product List</h3>
            <small>
                <a href="{{ route('adminHome') }}">{{ trans('backLang.home') }}</a> /
                <a href="#">Product List</a>
            </small>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="table"  >
            <thead class=" primary">
                <tr >
                    <th class="text-center">Category</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Title</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Make</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Rate</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($records as $record)
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">{{$record->section_title}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{$record->title_en}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{$record->make}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{$record->rate}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">@if($record->status != 1) Used
                        @else New @endif
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#table').DataTable();
        $("#checkAll").click(function () {
            $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });
        $("#action").change(function () {
            if (this.value == "delete") {
                $("#submit_all").css("display", "none");
                $("#submit_show_msg").css("display", "inline-block");
            } else {
                $("#submit_all").css("display", "inline-block");
                $("#submit_show_msg").css("display", "none");
            }
        });
    } ;

</script>
@section('footerInclude')
@endsection
```

Comment: +1, Most importantly jquery needs to be loaded first since the OP is using `$` without waiting for the document to be fully loaded.

Comment: Correct @Devon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply@faizan. I paste the above code but still facing the same problem. Any help??

Comment: getlist:133 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (getlist:133)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.3.js:3232)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.3.js:3362)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.3.js:3582)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.3.js:3617)